# Delete sql rows with multiple values within where IDs do not have a match in another table

Tags: mysql

I have two table:

Table: Options

```
Options

Id         xItems

-         ItemA,ItemB,ItemC,etc
```

Table: Items

```
Items      
    Id
    -
```

I am attempting to delete all Items rows that are not listed within Options.xitems

I attempted to execute the SQL statement

```
DELETE FROM items
Where items.id NOT IN (SELECT xitems FROM options)
```

However the problem is that multiple values are contained within XItems and I only managed to delete rows where Item.Id was the first or only value.
Would appreciate any kind help

**EDIT:** The following update added from the OP's post as an Answer.

The server is MySQL(tags edited accordingly) which allows one to enter an SQL statement below to execute against any database table or tables. I am a front end dev and get confused with this stuff.

John, I ran the code you posted. Here is the acutal code I applying against backedup test tables

```
DELETE FROM xbak514q_ecom_prodoptionsel
WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(xbak514q_ecom_prodoptionsel.id, (SELECT xprodoptionsel FROM xbak514q_ecom_prodoptions))
```

which returned the following error:

> A problem was encountered while executing the SQL statement submitted.
>   The error was reported as: The MySQL extension encountered a problem
>   submitting an SQL statement. MySQL reported the error as: Subquery
>   returns more than 1 row

This database was configured by a software company who set up an e-comm site. The Items, Product options and selection items(add ons) are quite extensive. Should I consider reformatting the tables?

Again thanks for your kind help

Comment: Can you show some sample data, and what is being deleted vs. what you expect to be deleted?

Comment: You speak correctly when you say "the problem is that multiple values are contained within XItems".  This is a severe normalization failure.  Columns should hold atomic values, where "atomic" is a bit slippery but basically describes values that cannot be divided into multiple parts having independent significance.

Comment: Also, is it MySQL or SQL Server?, please add only the relevant tags to your question

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using `find_in_set()`??

```
DELETE FROM items
WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(items.id, (SELECT xitems FROM options))
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/082f8/1)**

### NOTE:

`find_in_set()` is only for MySQL but since you have it tagged for both this may or may not be the solution. however the function looks for a comma separated list that is a single string or item and takes the first argument as the search string

### RECOMMENDATION.

you should **NEVER** store data in the database as a comma separated list like that.. it causes **HUGE** issues in the future. please consider normalizing your database. if you want a way to do that just post a comment and I'll write up a query that will normalize it for you.